# Change HTML table style from Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have this table:

```
<table id="classTable" style="width:40%">
<tr>
    <td>WCOB 2053: Business Foundations</td>
    <td>MWF 10:45am</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>MATH 2043C: Survey of Calculus</td>
    <td>MW 12:55pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ISYS 2103: Business Information Systems</td>
    <td>MW 4:30pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ISYS 2263: Principles of Information Systems</td>
    <td>TTh 9:30am</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CSCE 3193: Programming Paradigms</td>
    <td>TTh 11:00am</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>SCMT 2103: Introduction to Supply Chain Management</td>
    <td>TTh 6:00pm</td>
</tr>
```

I want to control the visibility of this table with a button that calls a function so I think I need to be using

```
style="display:none";
```

but how do I change this in the function? I'm assuming something like

```
document.getElementById("classTable").style.display = "none";
```

but I can't find a documentation for this anywhere.

Comment: Did you try this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var show = true;
var table = document.getElementById('classTable');
var toggleTable = function()
{
    table.style.display = show ? 'none' : 'block';
    show = !show;
}
```

```html
<table id="classTable" style="width:40%">
<tr>
    <td>WCOB 2053: Business Foundations</td>
    <td>MWF 10:45am</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>MATH 2043C: Survey of Calculus</td>
    <td>MW 12:55pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ISYS 2103: Business Information Systems</td>
    <td>MW 4:30pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>ISYS 2263: Principles of Information Systems</td>
    <td>TTh 9:30am</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CSCE 3193: Programming Paradigms</td>
    <td>TTh 11:00am</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>SCMT 2103: Introduction to Supply Chain Management</td>
    <td>TTh 6:00pm</td>
</tr>
</table>

<button onclick="toggleTable()">Toggle table</button>
```

table.style.display = 'none'; works perfectly fine!

Comment: Thank you! I did try table.style.display = 'none'; before I posted here, but I guess I mistyped or something before because it definitely wasn't working. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this on your button:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("classTable").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to do but couldn't get it to work an now it will, thank you! To people criticizing it, anything more complicated would not go along with what we've done in class so I'm glad to have this simple version as I think it's what my professor wanted